# RavenDB cannot define the Map Reduce for my types

Tags: c#, join, mapreduce, ravendb

My POCO objects;

```
public class Chest
    {

       public Chest()
       {
           this.KeyIds = new List<string>();
           this.Keys = new List<Page>();
       }
       public string Id { get; set; }

       public string Name { get; set; }

        [JsonIgnore]
       public IList<Key> Keys { get; set; }

       public IList<string> KeyIds { get; set; }
    }

public class UserKey
{
   public string UserName { get; set; }

   public string Id { get; set; }

   public UserKey()
   {
       this.KeyIds = new List<string>();
   }

   public   IList<string> KeyIds { get; set; }
}
```

I want the chests which my user keys has.

For example: User has KeyIds=1,2,3

And Has Chests like:

Chest1: Name:Hollywood, KeyIds=1

Chest2:Name:Mollywood, KeyIds=2

Chest3:Name:Barcelona, KeyIds=1,2

Chest4:Name:Madrid, KeyIds=1,2,3

Chest5:Name:Dortmund, KeyIds=4

Chest6:Name:Milano, KeyIds=4,5

I will give the username as parameter to query and result should return me

Chest1, Chest2, Chest3, Chest4 objects.

Thanks. Regards

Answer (score 1):

Load the user instance, and then get the keys that it has.
Then do an In query on the keys.

Comment: I want to do this in 1 query, I will give the user key ids to query the chest.

Comment: You cannot do that in a single query, that require computation during query, which isn't allowed.

Comment: Can you help me to write this queries.